# Angular 2 DOM manipulation after load

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build  element after I get http get response from server based on data I get. Is it possible to create components which will update DOM after they get new data? i.e.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to build such table with angular2 components after page is loaded. I was trying to do this with to components

```
@Component({
  selector: 'thead',
  template: `
    <tr>
      <th *ng-for="#th of tableHeaders">{{ th.name }}</th>
    </tr>
  `
})
export class TableHeader {
  tableHeaders: Array<any>;

  constructor () {
    this.tableHeaders = [];
  }

  addHeader(header) {
    this.tableHeaders.push(header)
  }
}
```

and somewhere else

```
...
this.http.get('/some/url')
   .map(res: Response => res.json())
   .subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.tableColumns.length; i += 1) {
            TableHeader.addHeader(data.tableColumns[i])
          }
      }
   )
...
```

Am I going in right direction whit that?

Answer (score 0):

Without a plnkr, I don'know what you met exactly. But maybe you can solve this by using NgZone. Usage is below.

```
import {NgZone} from 'angular2/angular2'

constructor(private ngZone:NgZone)
{
  this.ngZone.run(
    () => {
       //code to update view like add a item to array.
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this just with simple class properties. I just had to use @ViewChild on my parent component. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using a service, so it serves as a data provider.

Example can be found here, clicking the add button will get a list of people from `http.get` and append the result to the existing people array.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NCxUCAPTqZUc0Gbpey6v?p=preview

```
//a simple service
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class PeopleService {
  constructor(http:Http) {
    this.people = http.get('api/people.json').map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

And then you call the subscribe to get the people array in your component.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2'
import {PeopleService} from './peopleService'
import {Person} from './person'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [PeopleService]
})
@View({
  template: `
    <div>
      <my-person *ng-for="#person of people" [name]="person.name"></my-person>
    </div>
    <button (click)="addName()">Add name</button>
  `,
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, Person]
})
export class App {
  people: Array<string>;
  constructor(public peopleService:PeopleService) {
    this.people = [  {"id": 0, "name": "Plunker"}];
  }

  addName() {
    var app = this;
    this.peopleService.people.subscribe(data => Array.prototype.push.apply(app.people, data));
  }
}
```